# jQuery btn to close div if made active

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I need the `.menu` button to **close** the `.slides` container if it was opened by one of the `[name=toggler]` radio buttons.

So if the state of the `.slide` is `show` and the `.menu` button is clicked, hide `.slides`.

`.slides` can only be opened by the `[name=toggler]` radio buttons, but are made hidden by clicking the `.menu` button.

```js
$('.menu-btn').click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggle("slide");
});
$(function() {
  $("[name=toggler]").click(function() {
    $('.slide').hide();
    $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.flex,
.btn-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.menu,
.slide {
  display: none;
}

.btn,
.menu-btn {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  cursor: pointer
}

.slide {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex">
  <a href="#" class="menu-btn">Menu</a>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="btn-wrap">
      <label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="toggler" value="1"/>Slide 1</label>
      <label class="btn"><input type="radio" name="toggler" value="2"/>Slide 2</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide" id="blk-1">
    Slide 1
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="blk-2">
    Slide 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have to do a check on `.menu-btn` click, whether the .slide div is visible or not. If visible hide it also uncheck the radio button.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/johnsackson/pen/NMNmyb

```
$(".menu-btn").click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggle("slide");
  if($(".slide").is(":visible")) {
    $(".slide").hide();
    $("[name=toggler]").prop("checked", false);
  }
});
$(function() {
  $("[name=toggler]").click(function() {
    $(".slide").hide();
    $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if I wanted to keep the last selected slide `:visible` when the `.menu-btn` is toggled to show the `.slides`? So the `.menu-btn` controls the `.slides` container to show/hide the last selected `.slide`

Comment: Not sure i understood your requirement, however try removing '$("[name=toggler]").prop("checked", false);' line and let me know if that is what you are looking at.

Comment: I posted a detailed requirement here if you have time to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051012/show-hide-div-if-opened-by-radio-selection